# GET request works in postman but fails with Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, postman

I'm sending GET request to the same endpoint with the same headers, including the Bearer, but while i get 200 and the correct JSON as a result when calling from Postman, when i send the request using Axios in my (Vue) project i get 302.

the call from the local project , running on localhost:8080 (in case its useful) is as follows:

```
  const { authToken, userID } = store.getters.authUser
  const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: '/' + userID,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  axios(config)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      return res
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
```

while in postman all i do is create a GET request with the same url and all i add in the headers is the 'Bearer ...'

the error i get from axios is :

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:87)
```

and response status is 302 , any idea whats going on here??

both values of `userID` and the `authToken` exists and are equal to the same values i used with postman, same goes for the url

Comment: did you set {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} in header?

Comment: yes i have set the header

Comment: Have you tried to use the url `http://localhost:8080/${userID}` ?

Comment: i'm not working against local server...the request goes to another server

Comment: Have you tried to use the complete address of the server ?

Comment: Did you check the values of vue store? It looks like you don't have a `userId` and/or `authToken` in store which is causing the redirects. When using Postman, you must be entering these details manually, so the server gets the data it requires to process the data.

Comment: both values of userId and te token exists and are equal to the same values i used with postman

Comment: i also use the complete address of the server, again same as the one i use in axios

Comment: A 302 is a Moved … and should be accompanied by a `Location` header which the browser should follow automatically. Is the `Location` header missing? If so, that's the API being broken.

Comment: **Don't** set `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. You're making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content of!

Comment: In case your are using Chrome dev tools to see the axios request: could you do a "Copy as cURL" from the network tab and add the command in your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same issue. My `URL` is related to GitHub and it works when I open in Chrome with redirection and woks in PostMan but it does not work in `Axios` and shows the same error as you have mentioned. Were you able to find the issue and fix it? How did you resolve it? Any suggestion would be appreciated.